# Google play billing library 5.0

Tags: android, kotlin, play-billing-library

I'm using google play billing library 5.0 for subscription and getting the error of `onSkuDetailsResponse: -2 Client does not support ProductDetails.` after successfully initializing the billing library.

Device : Redmi 9i (Android 10)

Answer (score 0):

Your device's play store app doesn't support this. Please check [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#process-the-result). At the end of this section please read the note carefully. [image]